# Swift Apple Mach-O linker error

Tags: ios, swift3, swift4, xcode9, mach-o

I converted my project from swift 3 to swift 4 and am using the latest version of xcode 9. On building, I get the following error :

`Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "__T0So22AVCapturePhotoSettingsC12AVFoundation01_abC16SwiftNativeTypesACWP", referenced from:
      __T06SpotMi8CameraVCC12capturePhotoyypF in CameraVC.o
  "__T012AVFoundation39_AVCapturePhotoSettingsSwiftNativeTypesPAAE016availablePreviewc11PixelFormatG0SaySo8NSNumberCGfg", referenced from:
      __T06SpotMi8CameraVCC12capturePhotoyypF in CameraVC.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64`

I am out of clues. Any help will be much appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: @aakasj-dave You have cocoapods ?

Comment: I get this error, too! Did you solve it?

Comment: @RajeshRajendiran yes i am using alot of pods. Can that be an issue?

Comment: @datayeah not untill now. Have posted this in apple forum too.

Comment: @RajeshRajendiran i suppose this has something to do with the capturePhotoSettings.

Comment: i found a solution. see my answer!

Comment: @datayeah wheres the answer??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a bug in XCode9. Apple inadvertendly made some functions in AVFoundation private.

Workaround:

Change `availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes` to `__availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes` in your source.

Same goes for the following:

`supportedColorSpaces -> __supportedColorSpaces`

`supportedFlashModes -> __supportedFlashModes`

`availableRawPhotoPixelFormatTypes -> __availableRawPhotoPixelFormatTypes`

`availablePhotoPixelFormatTypes -> __availablePhotoPixelFormatTypes`

Then it might compile!
Good Luck!

Comment: Alright, lemme try it out and update you. Thanks though

Comment: Okay! Its the double _ . I was putting a single one.

Comment: Thanks! How did you get the idea? Who would know to add two under-scores.